# Changing WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL in wp-config.php does not register?

Tags: wp-config

I tried to add this to the end of my wp-config.php

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/somedir');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/somedir');
```

however, echo immediately after that shows the old values (with wp-content value). I tried echo because in wp admin I couldn't see the theme from new location, of course.

I have installed wp in example.com/wp subdirectory and site itself is example.com - I copied over .htaccess and index.php over to the root and everything is working fine, I just need to move wp-content into another folder over at root also with a different name.

Comment: slash `/` before somedir is superfificous (double) in line 1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have probably added the definitions too late. If in fact you added that "to the end" of `wp-config.php` then you added it after these lines:

```
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

If so, then those [constants are already defined](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-settings.php#L26) ([`wp_initial_constants`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/default-constants.php#L15)) and you cannot redefine a constant after it is already defined.

Make your edits earlier, before:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Comment: To add to the correct answer, it's recommended to check, if a constant is already 'not defined' before defining it.

Comment: @Pothi : Yes, generally a good idea, but if you `define` the constants where the WordPress Core intends there should be no problem.