# Moving wp-content folder

Tags: customization, themes

I want to move wp-content folder out of wordpress installation folder. I have set

`define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/opt/deployer/wordpress/wp-content' );` in wp-config.php file. But themes stopped working on site.

Please help me.

Comment: *Where* in `wp-config.php` did you add your `define()` line? It needs to go *before* the `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy bloggin.! */` line. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103945/changing-wp-content-dir-and-wp-content-url-in-wp-config-php-does-not-register .

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on why are you moving the folder.

If you just need to folder to be moved but leave the URLs the same then you will need to adjust yout apache/nginx config files to point to the right directory when serving a request for a url of the type /wp-content/...

If you need to adjust the url as well then you need to also define appropriate `WP_CONTENT_URL`

Comment: I can set the WP_CONTENT_URL but I am not sure how to do that. WP_CONTENT folder is not inside wordpress installation,it somewhere else in filesystem.

Comment: If the directory is not accessable from outside by a url then you need to change your webserver config.

Comment: Can you please share what changes I need to make in NGINX configuration..?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder as blog.

put wp-contant folder in blog folder.

define this line in config.php

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy bloggin.! */

define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(**FILE**) . '/blog/wp-content' );